# ASP.NET Create textbox on fly using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, textbox

I want to create a textbox on the fly (in the comment section im creating). Now I would like your opinion on whats the best solution. I was thinking about using a webmethod and add a textbox control dynamically, but since this requires a call to the server I'm not sure if that's the best option. Or can i also spawn a textbox using plain old javascript and still getting it's value on postback?

Thanks again guys

Kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the TextBox using ordinary HTML input element on page and set its visibility property to collapsed using style tag then in code behind make it visible.

HTML Tag:

```
<input id="myTextBox" type="text" style="visibility: collapse;" />
```

Javascript:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("myTextBox");
txt.style.visibility = "visible";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: if you want to access the textbox from server side also add a attribute in the HTML tag as follows:

<input id="myTextBox" type="text" style="visibility: collapse;" runat="server" />

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new element using plain old JavaScript:

```
var textbox = document.createElement("textarea");
textbox.className = "my-textarea"; //Styling with CSS 
document.getElementById("myelement").appendChild(textbox);
```